# Dividing a Turtle variable by Patch variable giving Error

Tags: netlogo, division

I am writing some codes. Turtles and patches are set to have values. None of them have zero value. I am trying to divide surface-water (farmer-own) with an average values of DWS(patch variable) around farmer. I am getting error of division by zero  while I suppose no value is zero. I request to identify the error and help me to made correction. here are the codes

```
Globals [ Water-Availbility]
Breed [farmers farmer]
farmers-own [ WA sw ]  

patches-own [
GW wtd DWS] 
to setup
   clear-all
    setup-farmers
    ask patches [ ifelse random 4 = 0 [
    set dws  distance-from-water-source + random-float 50
    set WTD DWS / depth-WT + random-float 1
    set GW Ground-water + random-float 5.005  +  (100 / wtd)
    set pcolor blue
  ]

     [ set dws  distance-from-water-source + random-float 100 
       set WTD DWS / depth-WT + 5 + random-float 5 
       set GW Ground-water + random-float 5.005  +  (100 / wtd)
       set pcolor red]]
end
to setup-farmers

create-farmers num-farmers [move-to one-of patches
                             set shape "person"
                              set sw  random 100 + surface-water / sum [DWS] of patches in-radius 1 / count patches in-radius 1 
                              SET WA  sw +  sum [gw] of patches in-radius 1 / count patches in-radius 1 + [gw] of self
]
end
```

[image: Interface of codes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is just a scheduling issue in your `setup`- you call `setup-farmers` before you setup your patches, so all patches have a `DWS` equal to zero when the farmers query that value. `sum [DWS] of patches in-radius 1` is therefore 0, making your denominator zero. Change your setup to something like the below and you should be good to go.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ 
    ifelse random 4 = 0 [
      set dws  50 + random-float 50
      set WTD DWS / 50 + random-float 1
      set GW 50 + random-float 5.005  +  (100 / wtd)
      set pcolor blue
    ] [ 
      set dws  50 + random-float 100 
      set WTD DWS / 50 + 5 + random-float 5 
      set GW 50 + random-float 5.005  +  (100 / wtd)
      set pcolor red 
    ]
  ]
  setup-farmers
  reset-ticks
end
```